# Comparing checked checkbox values with values in DB

Tags: php, database, function, checkbox, compare

Let's say I have a huge premade database with car information(columns) as followed(this DB already has like 3000 rows):

ID .... CAR NAME .... WHEEL SIZE .... YEAR OF PRODUCTION .... MAX SPEED

On mainpage user inputs 4 kinds of information in a form:

```html
    <form action="sanitize.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="text" name="car_name"  placeholder="CAR NAME"><br>
  <input type="text" name="wheel_size" placeholder="WHEEL SIZE"><br>
  <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="YEAR of PROD"><br>
  <input type="text" name="max_speed" placeholder="MAX SPEED"><br>
     <button>Submit </button>
  </form>
```

I have created sanitize.php for future use if I’d like to insert those values into DB and it looks smth like this:

```html
<?php

$dbServerName = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "cars";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServerName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
// Sanitize POST Array
 $POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

 $car_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $POST['car_name']);
 $wheel_size = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$POST['wheel_size']);
 $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$POST['year']);
 $max_speed = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$POST['max_speed']);

session_start();
  $_SESSION['car_name'] = $car_name;
  $_SESSION['wheel_size'] = $wheel_size;
  $_SESSION['year'] = $year;
  $_SESSION['max_speed'] = $max_speed;

// Redirect to decide page
header('Location: decide.php');
?>
```

On decide.php page are checkboxes and based on which checkboxes user chooses to tick, the website will echo out the number of occurances it is inside database.

```html
<form action="function.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name = "checkbox[]" value="<?php echo   $_SESSION['car_name']; ?>"> Car name<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name = "checkbox[]" value="<?php echo   $_SESSION['wheel_size']; ?>"> Wheel size<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name = "checkbox[]" value="<?php echo   $_SESSION['year']; ?>"> YEAR of PROD<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name = "checkbox[]" value="<?php echo   $_SESSION['max_speed']; ?>"> MAX SPEED<br>

  <button>Submit CHOICES</button>
</form>
```

For example if user ticked only car name and clicked button Submit CHOICES, the website will redirect the user to function.php and count and echo out the number of rows from DB that has the same name as he enetered.

If he ticked year of production AND wheel size the webpage(function.php) will count and echo out number of rows from DB where year of production AND wheel size are just like user entered.

Same goes for 3 ticked checkboxes, if he decides to tick max speed, year of production, and car name the webpage(function.php) will count and echo out number of rows from DB where max speed && year of production && car name match the user’s input.

I'd like to know if there's a way to create a function for this, not just manually using if statement for each case. It would be never-ending code like this if I decided that I need to add some extra columns into my database.

If statement in php would look smth like this:

```html
$KAR = $_SESSION['car_name'];

            $sql="SELECT * FROM ecars WHERE car_name = '".$KAR"'";

  if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
      // Return the number of rows in result set
      $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
      printf("Number of cars which have same NAME as you entered: %d.\n",$rowcount);
      echo "<br>";
      // Free result set
      mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me ... but I don't understand what you’re trying to do. Can you post an example of what you "could" do using the if and I will help you find out a better way when I understand what you’re trying to achieve. Please show more code also.

Comment: I edited this post, hopefully it's easier to understand Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks that helped me understand better what you are trying to do. Looks to me that your main issue in your logic is that you can't identify the col name you need to query because you not passing that data. Try something like this:

```
<form action="function.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name = "checkbox[car_name]" value="<?php echo   $_SESSION['car_name']; ?>"> Car name<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name = "checkbox[wheel_size]" value="<?php echo   $_SESSION['wheel_size']; ?>"> Wheel size<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name = "checkbox[year]" value="<?php echo   $_SESSION['year']; ?>"> YEAR of PROD<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name = "checkbox[max_speed]" value="<?php echo   $_SESSION['max_speed']; ?>"> MAX SPEED<br>

  <button>Submit CHOICES</button>
</form>
```

Once you have the col name inside your checkbox array, you can use that so you don't need to manually do the query for every possibility.

```
<?php
// The $_POST['checkbox'] array needs to survive the sanitizing part
foreach($_SESSION['checkbox'] as $col=>$value){

    $sql="SELECT * FROM ecars WHERE $col = '$value'";
    $col_title = str_replace('_', ' ', $col);

    if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        // Return the number of rows in result set
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $vars = array($col_title, $rowcount); 
        printf("Number of %d which have same VALUE as you entered: %d.\n",$vars);
        echo "<br>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }   

}
?>
```

Let me know how that works out

Comment: I think it should work, but I always get this error:


Notice: Undefined index: checkbox in C:\xampp\htdocs\cars\function.php on line 11

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cars\function.php on line 11
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Make a var dump of $_SESSION['checkbox'] and make sure it's not empty. I suspect your sanitizing part may have played with the array.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, got it! And my final question is if there's a way to create something like this: User fullfilled the form and then he is redirected to decide.php and here he has to tick checkboxes of his choice. For example if he chooses to tick car name and wheel size the webpage will echo out number of rows that contains same car name and wheel size as user inputted AT THE SAME TIME! If he chooses to tick car name, wheel size and year of production the webpage will echo out number of rows that contain the same name,wheel,year as user inputted AT THE SAME TIME!!!

Comment: I managed to figure it out, anyways thank you, your advice was very helpful :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

you will need to build you query depending on the checkboxes ticked. like something below

```
select
    a.count_cars,
    b.count_wheel
from
(
select
        count(*) count_cars
from
    dc_cars
) a
inner join
(
    select
        count(*) count_wheel
    from dc_wheel
)b
```

*this may not be the best way to select, but just to give you an idea

So depending on what the user ticked, you will construct the select part and the inner join query if 2 or more is selected.